# Pie Chart Alignment issue using MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

In my application am using piechart. Using the following library
`api 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'`.

But am facing an issue the alignment problem.Attaching the screenshots,Please have a look on it:

[image: graph_1] [image: graph_2]

Code:

```
public static void chartDetails(PieChart mChart, Typeface tf) {
    mChart.animateXY(1400, 1400);
    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.setCenterTextTypeface(tf);
    mChart.setCenterText("");
    mChart.setCenterTextSize(10f);
    mChart.setCenterTextTypeface(tf);
    // radius of the center hole in percent of maximum radius
    mChart.setHoleRadius(45f);
    mChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(50f);
    Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
    l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP);
    l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.VERTICAL);
    l.setDrawInside(false);
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use outside values in order to keep clear your dataset names for small pieces of data.

For example, you could achieve something like that:

[image: Outside values]

Here is the code. This code is supposed to use when overriding a `PieChart`. If you are not overriding it, you should adapt this code to work with your `PieChart` directly, such as `mChart.setData();` instead of `setData();`.

```
PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, null);
dataSet.setSliceSpace(3f);
dataSet.setIconsOffset(new MPPointF(0, 40));
dataSet.setSelectionShift(5f);

// Outside values
dataSet.setXValuePosition(PieDataSet.ValuePosition.OUTSIDE_SLICE);
dataSet.setYValuePosition(PieDataSet.ValuePosition.OUTSIDE_SLICE);
dataSet.setValueLinePart1OffsetPercentage(100f); /** When valuePosition is OutsideSlice, indicates offset as percentage out of the slice size */
dataSet.setValueLinePart1Length(0.6f); /** When valuePosition is OutsideSlice, indicates length of first half of the line */
dataSet.setValueLinePart2Length(0.6f); /** When valuePosition is OutsideSlice, indicates length of second half of the line */
setExtraOffsets(0.f, 5.f, 0.f, 5.f); // Ofsets of the view chart to prevent outside values being cropped /** Sets extra offsets (around the chart view) to be appended to the auto-calculated offsets.*/

PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
data.setValueTextSize(10f);
data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
setData(data);
```

Comment: setDrawEntryLabels(false);
        setExtraOffsets(0.f, 5.f, 0.f, 5.f); can you tell what is this.

Comment: Don't understand your comment. You can test and modify these values as you want.

Comment: Ya that should apply like mChart.setExtraOffsets(0.f, 5.f, 0.f, 5.f);

Comment: `setDrawEntryLabels(false);` prevent showing the name of your dataset, set to true if your want to show it. `setExtraOffsets(0.f, 5.f, 0.f, 5.f);` as I've just edited sets extra padding in order to prevent outside values being cropped if the line is too long. You can test some values until you find thats you like.

Comment: @SunishaSindhu I've just added some JavaDoc provided by the library in order you to understand better what do each method.

Comment: Ya i understood..But i need to share some other image after i did what you suggest that screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173325/discussion-between-sunisha-sindhu-and-marc-estrada).

Answer (score 5):

Finally i got solution,Thanks to @Marc Estrada answer.But some more changes i have done.

[image]

The following thing code i have used,

```
  public static void chartDetails1(PieChart mChart, Typeface tf) {
    mChart.animateXY(1400, 1400);
    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.setCenterTextTypeface(tf);
    mChart.setCenterText("");
    mChart.setCenterTextSize(10f);
    mChart.setCenterTextTypeface(tf);
    // radius of the center hole in percent of maximum radius
    mChart.setHoleRadius(45f);
    mChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(50f);
    Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
    l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP);
    l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
    l.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
    l.setDrawInside(false);
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    mChart.setDrawEntryLabels(false);
    mChart.setExtraOffsets(25.f, 0.f, 25.f, 0.f);

    mChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
    mChart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.95f);
    mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
    mChart.setHoleColor(Color.WHITE);
    mChart.setTransparentCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
    mChart.setTransparentCircleAlpha(110);
    mChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(61f);
    mChart.setRotationAngle(0);
    // enable rotation of the chart by touch
    mChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(true);
    // mChart.setUnit(" €");
    // mChart.setDrawUnitsInChart(true);
    l.setEnabled(true);
    mChart.highlightValues(null);
    mChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
    /*new*/
    mChart.setHoleRadius(30f);
    mChart.setDrawCenterText(false);
    mChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(35f);

    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.setRotationEnabled(false);

    mChart.setEntryLabelColor(Color.WHITE);
    mChart.setEntryLabelTextSize(9f);

}

public static ArrayList<Integer> colorsList() {
    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    return colors;

}
public static PieData pieDatasetSlice(PieDataSet dataSet){
    dataSet.setXValuePosition(PieDataSet.ValuePosition.OUTSIDE_SLICE);
    dataSet.setYValuePosition(PieDataSet.ValuePosition.OUTSIDE_SLICE);
    dataSet.setValueLinePart1OffsetPercentage(100f); /** When valuePosition is OutsideSlice, indicates offset as percentage out of the slice size */
    dataSet.setValueLinePart1Length(0.6f); /** When valuePosition is OutsideSlice, indicates length of first half of the line */
    dataSet.setValueLinePart2Length(0.6f); /** When valuePosition is OutsideSlice, indicates length of second half of the line */
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(0f);
    PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
    data.setValueTextSize(5f);
    data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    return data;
}
```

After adding your entries add these lines,

```
    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(entries1, null);
    ArrayList<Integer> colors = Constants.colorsList();
    dataSet.setColors(colors);
    PieData data = Constants.pieDatasetSlice(dataSet);
```

If you want to see more details of each slice,do the following ,

- implements OnChartValueSelectedListener

Comment: Hi can you please share your code of how you are creating entries ?